# Responsive dashboard on css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a question. Does anyone have a css-grid template for an responsive dashboard. With the ability to hide the sidebar on large screens, but leave only the icons and the departing sidebar on a small screen. Without anything superfluous. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

***I believe you are looking for some CSS frameworks.***

> With the ability to hide the sidebar on large screens, but leave only the icons and the departing sidebar on a small screen.

This should be implemented manually and I don't think frameworks might even provide it.

---

list of some CSS frameworks that might help you:

- BootStrap
- Bulma
- Tailwind CSS
- Materialize
- Spectre
- Milligram
- Water.css
- Windi CSS
- Mobi.css

Answer (score 0):

Naive UI is a great library that has components like these.

https://www.naiveui.com/en-US/os-theme